# On the definition of a stationary process

Tags: mathematical-physics, stochastic-processes

I have come across various ways one refers to a process as stationary and cannot seem to get the equivalency and the level of rigor in each of them:

1. According to *Stochastic processes in physics and chemistry* by Van Kampen, a stationary process is one for which the probability distribution for the stochastic variable is independent of time. It also mentions that for a stationary Markov process, the transition probability $\text{P}_{1|1}$ does not depend on two times, but only on the time interval.
   $$
   \text{P}_{1|1}(y_{2}, t_{2} | y_{1}, t_{1}) = \text{T}_{\tau}(y_{2}|y_{1}) \text{ where } \tau = \text{t}_{2} - \text{t}_{1}    
   $$
2. Another definition, which I think is a widely accepted one and is probably the most rigorous one is that all the moments are invariant to a time shift:
   $$
   \langle X(\text{t}_{1})X(\text{t}_{2})X(\text{t}_{3})....X(\text{t}_{n}) \rangle = \langle X(\text{t}_{1}+\tau)X(\text{t}_{2}+\tau)X(\text{t}+\tau_{3})....X(\text{t}+\tau_{n}) \rangle \text{    for all n,} \tau
   $$
   This would imply that the mean $\langle X(t_{1}) \rangle$is a constant and the second moment $\langle X(\text{t}_{1})X(\text{t}_{2}) \rangle$ is a function of $\text{t}_{2} - \text{t}_{1}$. But this condition, although very rigorous, is not the easiest to check after the second moment.
3. Another test for stationarity I have come across is the following:
   $$
   \lim_{\tau \to +\infty} \text{T}_{\tau}(x'|x)  = \text{P}_{s}(x) \text{ where } \text{P}_{s}(x) \text{ is the stationary distribution}
   $$

Now, for example, if we were to consider the Wiener process for which condition (1) is satisfied and $\text{T}_{\tau}(y_{2}| y_{1}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi \tau)}}e^{\frac{-(x_{2} - x_{1})^{2}}{2 \tau}}$. But we know that Wiener process isn't stationary because the variance is time-dependent. So which definition is viable in order to quickly check if the process is stationary? Although I understand (hand-wavily) as to what a stationary process is, I don't get the other definitions except for the second one. Could someone clear this notion out for me, preferably rigorously?

Comment: I will expand later as answer, but on the top of my head I would say that a stochastic process is stationary iff its canonical transition matrix $Q$ is time invariant, that is $d P(t)/dt = Q(t)\cdot P(t) = 0$, where $P(t)$ is the probability vector, as $P(y,t)$ is the total probability of the process being in state $y$ at time $t$.